# Accessing Lumen public folder from Vagrant

Tags: laravel, vagrant, lumen, homestead

I'm currently experimenting with Lumen from inside an Homestead Vagrant box. My homestead box is up and running, and I accessed the machine with `vagrant ssh`.

I then created a new folder, and installed Lumen with: `composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer"`. Then I created a new Lumen project with `lumen new blog`.

This created all the structure of the new Lumen project. My problem is that now, I want to access the project in the browser. So, following the tutorial on the Lumen website I could do this with PHP in built server, like `php -S localhost:8000 -t public`.

The problem is that I'm inside a Vagrant Homestead machine, so when I try to go to localhost:8000 I get a `This site can't be reached. localhost refused to connect` error.

Any idea on how can I fix this?

Comment: Where did you run `lumen new blog`? Take a look at adding new sites to homestead https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#adding-additional-sites

Comment: Can't seem to find the Homestead.yaml file anywhere...

Comment: Have you edited your Vagrantfile to configure your network such as `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"` ? When you make a change like this be sure to run `vagrant reload`. To find your Homestead.yaml file I recommend running `sudo find / -iname Homestead.yaml`